# Mozilla scroller jquery div not scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, mozilla

I have a div with overflow auto.

I want that if user scroll page and if that div with scroller comes then it scroll that div first and then scroll main body scroller.

In my case it is working fine in chrome but in mozilla it is not scrolling that div if you scroll page continuously.

here is my html

```
<p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem sumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsum</p>


<div class="scroller">

<p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ips</p><p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipmlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorerem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem </p><p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem lorem </p>
```

please suggest me.
https://jsfiddle.net/46eejkmw/1/

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fq19n473/1/

you can use this jquery :

```
var i=0;
var docsc=$(document).scrollTop();
$(document).scroll(function(){
    i+=30;
  var divsc=$('.scroller').scrollTop();
  if(divsc < $('.scroller').height()-31){
    $('html, body').prop("scrollTop", docsc);
    $('.scroller').animate({
        "scrollTop":i
    },100);
  }else{
    i=0;
    docsc=$(document).scrollTop();
  }
});
```

Comment: its not that much smooth. and it scroll that div initially. I want that if cursor is not that div then it scroll that div and all that happen while user scrolling page continuously.
But anyway thanks for your help.